# Is it possible to connect from a remote browser to my CocoaHttpServer?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoahttpserver

I've been trying to find a solution to run an http server on an iOS device, which is accessible from anywhere as long as the encompassing app is open and running.

While searching for solutions I've come across several libraries, one of which is Cocoahttpserver https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer

While I see many people use this for setting up a local httpserver and accessing it from the same app, I am not sure if this can be accessed from a remote browser--for example my desktop browser. So here are my questions:

1. Is this possible? (running an iOS web server which can be accessed from anywhere, not just local network)
2. If it is possible, is it possible to set a static domain that will redirect to my iOS server?

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, it can be achieved. Either use the CocoaHTTPServer, which is a great library - or you can look at some tutorials on the net, like this one http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html

2) Unfortunately no, because the devices will have different IP depending on the internet connection, and the domain name can be only used with one defined IP address. You could also use the Bonjour name, however it would be probably easier to use the IP address.